# matlab: summing if/elseif displayed variables in a for loop

Tags: matlab

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the sum of displayed strings in a for loop. for example, assuming:

```
a=5;
b=10;
c=15;
d=20;


if sum(x)==1    
  disp(num2str(a))    
  elseif sum(x)==2    
  disp(num2str(b))    
elseif sum(x)==3    
  disp(num2str(c))    
elseif sum(x)==4    
  disp(num2str(d))    
else disp('0')
```

If I get the results in a for loop:

```
loop 1 gets: a=5

loop 2 gets: b=10

loop 3 gets: d=20

loop 4 gets: b=10
```

Is there any way I can get the sum of results, in this case being a+b+d+b=45 ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "get the results in a for loop"? I cannot really understand how your program is structured and why you cannot simply add the results.

Answer (score 0):

A friend has showed me the answer, here it is:

```
if sum(x)==1
    disp([num2str(a)])
    results=results+a;
elseif sum(x)==2
    disp([num2str(b)])
    results=results+b;
elseif sum(x)==3
    disp([num2str(c)])
    results=results+c;
elseif sum(x)==4
    disp([num2str(d)])
    results=results+d;
else disp('0')
end
disp(results)
```

Comment: You should edit the original question if this answer is what you meant to ask... Or is this the answer?

Comment: yeah this is the answer. oh my goodness i'm so messed up after 2 whole days of matlab.